# Reflection.Emit InvalidProgramException

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I´m currently trying to create a "Mock" for an interface using Reflection.Emit.
Therefore I created a base class that I use for all dynamically generated mocks.
For properties in the interface I want to call a "Get" Method in the base class that returns the property value.

```
public class Mock
{
  public static TIf Wrap<TIf>() where TIf : class
  {
    if (!typeof(TIf).IsInterface)
      throw new Exception(typeof(TIf) + " is no interface");

    var asmBuilder = Thread.GetDomain().DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var modBuilder = asmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Mock", true);
    var typename = "ImplOf" + typeof(TIf).Name.Replace(" ", "") + ".Mock";
    var typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(typename, TypeAttributes.Public, typeof(WrapperBase));

    typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(TIf));

    // methods
    foreach (var meth in typeof(TIf).GetMethods())
    {
      var del = typeof(WrapperBase).GetMethod(meth.ReturnType != typeof(void) ? "TryCallMethod" : "TryCallMethodOneWay");

      var mb = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(meth.Name, meth.Attributes ^ MethodAttributes.Abstract);
      mb.SetParameters(meth.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType)?.ToArray());
      mb.SetReturnType(meth.ReturnType);
      var mbil = mb.GetILGenerator();
      mbil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
      mbil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, meth.Name);
      for (var i = 0; i < meth.GetParameters().Length; i++)
      {
        mbil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg, i + 1);
      }

      mbil.Emit(OpCodes.Call, del);
      mbil.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    }

    // properties
    foreach (var prop in typeof(TIf).GetProperties())
    {
      var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(prop.Name, prop.Attributes, prop.PropertyType, null);

      if (prop.CanRead)
      {
        var getterDelegate = typeof(WrapperBase).GetMethod("TryGetProperty");
        var getter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + prop.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, prop.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);

        var gil = getter.GetILGenerator();
        gil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);
        gil.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getterDelegate);
        gil.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, prop.PropertyType);
        gil.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getter);
      }

      if (prop.CanWrite)
      {
        var setterDelegate = typeof(WrapperBase).GetMethod("TrySetProperty");
        var setter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + prop.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);

        var sil = setter.GetILGenerator();
        sil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        sil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, prop.Name);
        sil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        sil.Emit(OpCodes.Call, setterDelegate);
        sil.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setter);
      }
    }

    var retType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
    return retType.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(new object[0]) as TIf;
  }

  public abstract class WrapperBase
  {
    public event Func<string, object[], object> OnTryCallMethod;
    public event Action<string, object[]> OnTryCallMethodOneWay;
    public event Func<string, object> OnTryGetProperty;
    public event Action<string, object> OnTrySetProperty;

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object TryCallMethod(string name, object[] pars)
    {
      return OnTryCallMethod?.Invoke(name, pars);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void TryCallMethodOneWay(string name, object[] pars)
    {
      OnTryCallMethodOneWay?.Invoke(name, pars);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object TryGetProperty(string name)
    {
      return OnTryGetProperty?.Invoke(name);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void TrySetProperty(string name, object value)
    {
      OnTrySetProperty?.Invoke(name, value);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I always get an InvalidProgramException when trying to read a "mocked" property.
Setting the property (which will delegate the call also to some base class method) works fine, same for method calls.

For testing, I created a quite simple interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
  void Show(string text);

  string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Now I´m calling the mock like this:

```
  var wrapped = Mock.Wrap<ITest>();

  // ***************** works - EventHandler is called with correct parameters!
  ((Mock.WrapperBase)wrapped).OnTryCallMethodOneWay += (s, objects) => { };
  wrapped.Show("sss");

  // ***************** works - EventHandler is called with correct parameters!
  wrapped.Text = "";
  ((Mock.WrapperBase)wrapped).OnTrySetProperty += (s, val) => { };

  // ***************** does NOT work - getting InvalidProgramException
  ((Mock.WrapperBase)wrapped).OnTryGetProperty += s => "";
  var t = wrapped.Text;
```

Comment: `var setter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + prop.Name, MethodAttributes.Public, typeof(void), Type.EmptyTypes);` is defining a method that takes no arguments (since you've provided no types for the arguments). This is incorrect. Also, can you show full working code? Including the code that's implementing your interface, so we can replicate it?

Comment: Also, testing out your code seems to work fine, after making the change to the setter

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the TypeParameter. I added them, but the exception is still thrown...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of debugging, I've found your issue. I noticed that

`wrapped.Text = ""` was stepping into `TryCallMethodOneWay` when it's clearly written as calling `TrySetProperty`.

This is because `foreach (var meth in typeof(TIf).GetMethods())` is going to return you getter and setter methods. That is; you're defining the getters and setters twice.

This is solved by a simple check:

```
var properties = typeof(TIf).GetProperties();
var propertyMethods = properties.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.GetGetMethod(), p.GetSetMethod() }).ToLookup(p => p);

foreach (var meth in typeof(TIf).GetMethods())
{
    if (propertyMethods.Contains(meth))
        continue;
    ...
}
```

Now, you also have to mark your implementing methods as `Virtual` if they're to implement an interface. So, you'll need to change the code to be the following:

```
var getter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("get_" + prop.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, prop.PropertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
```

And

```
var setter = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("set_" + prop.Name, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual, typeof(void), new[] { prop.PropertyType });
```

And your code should work without issue